# Programmatically (PHP) Replacing Text in PDFs

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Whenever I attempt to change TJ or Tj operators programmatically with PHP, an unknown char (crossed square) appears:

```
(lorem)Tj >>> (ipsum)Tj // Broken
[(lor)9 (em)]TJ >>> (ipsum)Tj // Broken
(lorem)Tj >>> (123)Tj // Looks OK
[(lor)9 (em)]TJ >>> (123)Tj // Looks OK
```

Numbers are ok, but text chars look broken.

What am I missing? are there operators in other lines define TJs?

Comment: The font inside your PDF may be a subset (to save space) or use a custom encoding (mostly, for convenience).

Comment: Thats right!! Thank you!!!!